# Qt5ct configuration

Tags: linux, fedora

On Linux Fedora 31 x64 LXQt, when I run qt5ct (and others applications) via menu, I have the warning:
[image]

but when I run the same via bash, the result is correct:
[image]

I have also tried to set the environment variable in ~/bashrc and reboot, with no effects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution; I modified the file /usr/bin/startlxqt:
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=lxqt
with
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
reboot